# Pattern matching vs if-else

Tags: scala

I'm novice in Scala. Recently I was writing a hobby app and caught myself trying to use pattern matching instead of if-else in many cases.

```
user.password == enteredPassword match {
  case true => println("User is authenticated")
  case false => println("Entered password is invalid")
}
```

instead of

```
if(user.password == enteredPassword)
  println("User is authenticated")
else
  println("Entered password is invalid")
```

Are these approaches equal? Is one of them more preferrable than another for some reason?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
class MatchVsIf {
  def i(b: Boolean) = if (b) 5 else 4
  def m(b: Boolean) = b match { case true => 5; case false => 4 }
}
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to use the longer and clunkier second version.

```
scala> :javap -cp MatchVsIf
Compiled from "<console>"
public class MatchVsIf extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
public int i(boolean);
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   ifeq    8
   4:   iconst_5
   5:   goto    9
   8:   iconst_4
   9:   ireturn

public int m(boolean);
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_2
   3:   iconst_1
   4:   if_icmpne   11
   7:   iconst_5
   8:   goto    17
   11:  iload_2
   12:  iconst_0
   13:  if_icmpne   18
   16:  iconst_4
   17:  ireturn
   18:  new #14; //class scala/MatchError
   21:  dup
   22:  iload_2
   23:  invokestatic    #20; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
   26:  invokespecial   #24; //Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   29:  athrow
```

And that's a lot more bytecode for the match also.  It's *fairly* efficient even so (there's no boxing unless the match throws an error, which can't happen here), but for compactness and performance one should favor `if`/`else`.  If the clarity of your code is greatly improved by using match, however, go ahead (except in those rare cases where you know performance is critical, and then you might want to compare the difference).

Update: at 2.13.12, using `-opt:local` to remove a few bits of cruft, and a default case to obviate the `MatchError`:

```
scala> def f(b: Boolean) = (b) match { case true => 42 case _ => 27 }
def f(b: Boolean): Int

scala> :javap #f
  public int f(boolean);
    descriptor: (Z)I
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iconst_1
         1: iload_1
         2: if_icmpne     8
         5: bipush        42
         7: ireturn
         8: bipush        27
        10: ireturn
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 1
        frame_type = 8 /* same */
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      11     0  this   L$line3/$read$$iw;
            0      11     1     b   Z
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      b                              final

scala>
```

Comment: I'm just under impression of pattern matching. I think that's why I'm trying to use it everywhere :) Thanks, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: @Soteric That's a common phase for Scala programmers. You'll go through other, worse phases. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Like having type signatures spanning several lines?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I think it would be nice to compile a list of those "don't overdo" phases...

Comment: @paradigmatic There's a question about bad habits or pitfalls, iirc.

Comment: You can look at the difference in bytecode size as a bug. There is hope that the Scala compiler will optimize the pattern match to be as tight as the if-else in the future. Then it will only come down to readability, as it should.

Answer (score 31):

Don't pattern match on a single boolean; use an if-else.

Incidentally, the code is better written without duplicating `println`.

```
println(
  if(user.password == enteredPassword) 
    "User is authenticated"
  else 
    "Entered password is invalid"
)
```

Comment: D'oh. That should have been my example.

Answer (score 20):

One arguably better way would be to pattern match on the string directly, not on the result of the comparison, as it avoids "boolean blindness". http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/

One downside is the need to use backquotes to protect the enteredPassword variable from being shadowed.

Basically, you should tend to avoid dealing with booleans as much as possible, as they don't convey any information at the type level.

```
user.password match {
    case `enteredPassword` => Right(user)
    case _ => Left("passwords don't match")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Both statements are equivalent in terms of code semantics. But it might be possible that the compiler creates more complicated (and thus inefficient) code in one case (the `match`).

Pattern matching is usually used to break apart more complicated constructs, like polymorphic expressions or deconstructing (`unapply`ing) objects into their components. I would not advice to use it as a surrogate for a simple *if-else* statement - there's nothing wrong with *if-else*.

Note that you can use it as an expression in Scala. Thus you can write

```
val foo = if(bar.isEmpty) foobar else bar.foo
```

I apologize for the stupid example.

Answer (score 10):

It's 2020, the Scala compiler generates far more efficient bytecode in the pattern matching case. The performance comments in the accepted answer are misleading in 2020.

The pattern match generated byte code gives a tough competition to if-else at times pattern matching wins giving much better and consistent results.

One can use pattern match or if-else based on the situation & simplicity.
But the pattern matching has poor performance conclusion is no longer valid.

You can try the following snippet and see the results:

```
def testMatch(password: String, enteredPassword: String) = {
    val entering = System.nanoTime()
    password == enteredPassword match {
      case true => {
        println(s"User is authenticated. Time taken to evaluate True in match : ${System.nanoTime() - entering}"
        )
      }
      case false => {
        println(s"Entered password is invalid. Time taken to evaluate false in match : ${System.nanoTime() - entering}"
        )
      }
    }
  }


 testMatch("abc", "abc")
 testMatch("abc", "def")
    
Pattern Match Results : 
User is authenticated. Time taken to evaluate True in match : 1798
Entered password is invalid. Time taken to evaluate false in match : 3878


If else :

def testIf(password: String, enteredPassword: String) = {
    val entering = System.nanoTime()
    if (password == enteredPassword) {
      println(
        s"User is authenticated. Time taken to evaluate if : ${System.nanoTime() - entering}"
      )
    } else {
      println(
        s"Entered password is invalid.Time taken to evaluate else ${System.nanoTime() - entering}"
      )
    }
  }

testIf("abc", "abc")
testIf("abc", "def")

If-else time results:
User is authenticated. Time taken to evaluate if : 65062652
Entered password is invalid.Time taken to evaluate else : 1809
```

PS: Since the numbers are at nano precision the results may not accurately match to the exact numbers but the argument on performance holds good.

Comment: Do you know what scala version made these improvements? Unfortunately some of does don't write code in 2020 as we are stuck with Spark and 2.11 code. Hopefully we will get to 2.12 in the not too distant future!

Comment: This is a meaningless benchmark on the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

For the large majority of code that isn't performance-sensitive, there are a lot of great reasons why you'd want to use pattern matching over if/else:

- it enforces a common return value and type for each of your branches
- in languages with exhaustiveness checks (like Scala), it forces you to explicitly consider all cases (and noop the ones you don't need)
- it prevents early returns, which become harder to reason if they cascade, grow in number, or the branches grow longer than the height of your screen (at which point they become invisible).  Having an extra level of indentation will warn you you're inside a scope.
- it can help you identify logic to pull out.  In this case the code could have been rewritten and made more DRY, debuggable, and testable like this:

```scala
val errorMessage = user.password == enteredPassword match {
  case true => "User is authenticated"
  case false => "Entered password is invalid"
}

println(errorMesssage)
```

Here's an equivalent if/else block implementation:

```scala
var errorMessage = ""

if(user.password == enteredPassword)
  errorMessage = "User is authenticated"
else
  errorMessage = "Entered password is invalid"

println(errorMessage)
```

Yes, you can argue that for something as simple as a boolean check you can use an if-expression.  But that's not relevant here and doesn't scale well to conditions with more than 2 branches.

If your higher concern is maintainability or readability, pattern matching is awesome and you should use it for even minor things!

Comment: Using if/else does not require mutation. The equivalent of the ternary operator in Scala would solve this:

`val errorMessage = 
         if (user.password == enteredPassword)
           "User is authenticated"
         else
           "Entered password is invalid"`

Comment: I addressed this in my original comment: "Yes, you can argue that for something as simple as a boolean check you can use an if-expression. But that's not relevant here and doesn't scale well to conditions with more than 2 branches."

Comment: You wrote "Whereas writing this using if/else would have required mutation". That's still incorrect. You don't need mutation for if/else as long as all branches are of the same type. Ex: `val k = if (false) "1" else if (false) "2" else "3"`

Comment: I'd hoped that the comment I mentioned earlier would have superseded the line you quoted - an if-expression/ternary statement is not the same as an if/else block (and therefore not relevant to the original question), and doesn't readably scale to more than 2 branches.  

It is possible to enclose an if/else block in braces and use that value, but I don't believe that's idiomatic.  In any case, I've updated my answer to remove confusion.

Comment: Don't confuse your opinion with facts. If'/else scales fine for multiple branches. Pattern match is also great for ... matching patterns.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: True/false - by the definition of pattern matching - is a pattern. It is true or it is false.  It is always true or false.  It has a predictable pattern. If you can use true/false as part of pattern matching in *any* case, what makes it invalid when the only possible matches are true and false.  If/else is probably more of a specialized form of pattern matching than anything else... because it only support the true/false pattern.

Comment: first bullet point is wrong or misleading, as match is lub of branches, the same as if-else.

Answer (score 3):

I am here to offer a different opinion:
For the specific example you offer, the second one (if...else...) style is actually better because it is much easier to read.

In fact, if you put your first example into IntelliJ, it will suggest you to change to the second (if...else...) style. Here is the IntelliJ style suggestion:

```
Trivial match can be simplified less... (⌘F1) 

Suggests to replace trivial pattern match on a boolean expression with a conditional statement.
Before:
    bool match {
      case true => ???
      case false => ???
    }
After:
    if (bool) {
      ???
    } else {
      ???
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'v came across same question, and had written tests:

```
     def factorial(x: Int): Int = {
        def loop(acc: Int, c: Int): Int = {
          c match {
            case 0 => acc
            case _ => loop(acc * c, c - 1)
          }
        }
        loop(1, x)
      }

      def factorialIf(x: Int): Int = {
        def loop(acc: Int, c: Int): Int = 
            if (c == 0) acc else loop(acc * c, c - 1)
        loop(1, x)
      }

    def measure(e: (Int) => Int, arg:Int, numIters: Int): Long = {
        def loop(max: Int): Unit = {
          if (max == 0)
            return
          else {
            val x = e(arg)
            loop(max-1)
          }
        }

        val startMatch = System.currentTimeMillis()
        loop(numIters)
        System.currentTimeMillis() - startMatch
      }                  
val timeIf = measure(factorialIf, 1000,1000000)
val timeMatch = measure(factorial, 1000,1000000)
```

timeIf  : Long = 22
timeMatch  : Long = 1092

Comment: This kind of benchmarking is, frankly, awful. Firstly, `System.currentTimeMillis()` has terrible precision; `System.nanoTime` is generally better. Even so, you should remove the impact of JIT compilation, garbage collection, etc. It's best to use a micro-benchmarking tool (such as [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/) to properly evaluate both approaches.

Comment: @MikeAllen yeah mate, it's been a long time ago) i am with you on micro benchmarking tools

Comment: Ha ha ha! Fair enough. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my environment (scala 2.12 and java 8) I get different results. Match performs consistently better in the code above:

timeIf: Long = 249
timeMatch: Long = 68