# Is there a way to use match with boolean

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I find using `match` more readable than `if`. If I have a `boolean` value, can I use it with `match`?

I usually do

```
if(!authorised) {...} else {..}
```

But I am unable to do

```
authorised match {
    case ??? //what here??
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern matching vs if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266822/pattern-matching-vs-if-else)

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use boolean literals:

```scala
authorised match {
   case true => /*true case*/
   case false => /*false case*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to pattern match, consider [mouse](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse) which provides extension methods for booleans, for example, consider [`fold`](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse/blob/7d5c1064c05e7ae09cde6cefff4a4848e7c21e8c/shared/src/main/scala/mouse/boolean.scala#L18)

```
authorised.fold("It is true", "It is false")
```

Comment: This is not a very standard pattern and is definitely overkill unless you are already using the library for some other features.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write:

```
authorised match {
  case true => ...
  case false => ...
}
```

Although intellij suggests refactoring to `if` statement.

Comment: is there another case than `true` or `false`?

Comment: @pme might be `null`

Comment: ah - I sometimes forget about that it is still possible to have null in Scala;)

Comment: Yeah, there's still java underneath, besides it's always a good practive to have a default case

Comment: @Andronicus As far as I know, Scala doesn't allow you to assign `null` to primitive types, so this additional clause is confusing and unreachable. The compiler will warn you about it, as shown in my edit to @Krzysztof 's answer.

Comment: @francoisr ok you're right, thanks for that comment

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using

```
authorised match {
    case true => ...
    case false => ...
}
```

Note that pattern matching on boolean values is not very idiomatic in Scala, and you'd probably be better off using the standard `if/else` expression. The compiler will actually not manage to generate the same efficient code for the pattern match, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9267277/2174693). It's very common for Scala beginners to get over-enthusiastic with pattern matching and start using it everywhere, but in the case of plain booleans, it really makes sense to stick with `if/else`.

---

Side-note: Other answers have mentioned using a default clause like

```scala
authorised match {
   case true => /*true case*/
   case false => /*false case*/
   case _ => /* default case */
}
```

This is unnecessary, as `Boolean` can only ever be `true` or `false`. Like all primitive types, they *cannot* be assigned `null` so the additional clause is useless and the compiler will justifiably warn you about it.

```
warning: unreachable code
       case _ => /* default case */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
authorised match {
  case true => // true case 
  case false => // false case
  case _ => // other case for exception or null
}
```

Comment: The additional clause is unnecessary. `null` cannot be assigned to a `Boolean` and this will not help manage any exception. The compiler will warn you about unreachable code in this clause.