# Scala avoid case _ => in matching

Tags: scala

How can I avoid always putting

```
case _ =>
```

at the end in Scala matching? It is sometimes possible that other values will be matched, but I only want to do something with the cases above the
"case _ =>"
case.

Comment: Case matching must be exhaustive. If you only care about the other cases, you still need to ensure your program handles the other cases _somehow_.

Comment: In some case a simple procedural `if` structure might be simpler. See this [not-duplicate yet related  question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9266822/2864740) comparing usages. At least one answer also covers why such a `case _` is required.

Comment: It's a code smell if you have a lot of these

Comment: If you match on sealed trait `case _` can be _safely_ skipped, nevertheless code has to be edited if new implementation of that trait is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `match` is a function like most things in Scala, so it returns a value and you need to return something for every possible `case`. If you are not doing anything in `case _` then you are returning `Unit` which, in turn, means that the code is relying on side effects and is non-functional.

So the best way to reduce the use of empty `case _ =>` in your code is to make it more functional, since this isn't used in functional code.

The alternative is to use a different mechanism for a multi-way branch, such as chained `if`, or chains of `Option/orElse`, or `find/collectFirst` on a list of operations.